# how can I print a text inserted in an editText

Tags: java, string, android-studio, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I need to create an AlertDialog where the user can complete 3 fields and then store them in String variables (and I would also like to print them to log). The problem is that once you enter a value and click on "Add" to log Comment1 **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {c6c367 VFED..CL is printed. ......THE. 0,0-0,0 # 7f080078 app: id / comment}** and instead comment2 remains empty.

Activity

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post); //set layout
    CommunicationController cc = new CommunicationController(this);
    SID = getIntent().getStringExtra("SESSION_ID");
    did = getIntent().getStringExtra("did");

    //Aggiunta POST
    FloatingActionButton addPost = findViewById(R.id.addPost);
    addPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("FAB","clickato");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PostActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = PostActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. new_post, null);
            builder.setTitle("Nuovo Post");
            builder.setMessage("Crea il tuo Post:");
            builder.setView(R.layout.new_post);

            //In case it gives you an error for setView(View) try
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_post, null));
            builder.setPositiveButton("Aggiungi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    EditText commento= (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
                    Log.d(TAG,"commento1"+commento);
                    EditText  stato= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.status);
                    EditText  ritardo= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.delay);

                    String comment = commento.getText().toString();
                    String status = stato.getText().toString();
                    String delay = ritardo.getText().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG,"commento2"+comment);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
}
```

AlertDialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Commento.."
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/comment" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Status.."
    android:id="@+id/status" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Delay.."
    android:id="@+id/delay"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: `Log.d(TAG,"commento1"+commento);` – That is implicitly calling `toString()` directly on the `EditText`, which is why you get that weird result. You forgot to call `getText()` on `commento` first. `builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_post, null));` – That `inflate()` call is creating a new instance of that layout that is completely separate from the instance created and assigned to `dialogView`, which is never shown on-screen anywhere. I'm not sure what the comment immediately above is trying to say, but you can change that line to `builder.setView(dialogView);` instead.

Comment: Also, make sure to call `findViewById()` on `dialogView` for `stato` and `ritardo`, too, like you're doing for `commento`.